# Is there statistic data of how many people access the site and from which country and what times?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, statistics

Do we have access to the stats of how many people access the site and from which country and what times ?

Like the analytics feature for the channel owner on YouTube.

I'm asking because I think it's interesting to know how many people are here from which country, what times the people from your country ask/answer, questions/answers ratio from each country, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Quant Cast](https://www.quantcast.com/math.stackexchange.com#!countries), "The volume of traffic originating from individual countries in a 30 day period", top 10 countries by number of unique visitors (also with % of total):

```
United States    947,545   47.47     
India            168,985    8.46     
United Kingdom   128,471    6.44     
Canada            97,695    4.89     
Australia         57,846    2.90     
Germany           42,893    2.15     
Pakistan          25,560    1.28     
South Korea       21,723    1.09     
Singapore         21,498    1.08     
France            20,061    1.00
```

No further breakdown (times of day or questions/answers) is available.

Another interesting measure is the traffic index: "e.g, an index of 500 indicates that the site gets five times as much of its traffic from the given country than the average Internet site." This serves as a measure of popularity, adjusted for the country's overall level of web activity. Among the countries with at least 1000 monthly uniques, Math.SE is most popular in:

1. Iran (1108)
2. Israel (666)
3. Nepal (605)
4. Lebanon (473)
5. India (430)
6. South Korea (388)
7. Hong Kong (361)
8. China (346)
9. Austria (336)
10. Sri Lanka (317)

The number in parentheses is the aforementioned index. The USA has index 85 (i.e., site popularity is below global),  between Latvia and Sudan.

Comment: Iran and Israel right after, that's interesting.

Comment: Huh, $10$ visitors from North Korea.